# Access is denied in spring oauth 2

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, oauth

I was looking through oAuth2.0 and I wrote this demo code, but I am not getting access token.
http://localhost:8080/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=restapp2&client_secret=secret&username=admin&password=admin

It shows Access is Denied as

```
<error_description>Access is denied</error_description>
<error>access_denied</error>
```

Please, help me out.

**spring-security.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd ">

<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <anonymous enabled="false"/>
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>

    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
</http>

<http pattern="/admin**" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_APP"/>
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
</http>
<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="test"/>
</bean>
<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="test/client"/>
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic"/>
</bean>
<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler"/>
<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager"/>
</bean>
<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService"/>
</authentication-manager>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_APP"/>
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
<bean id="clientDetailsUserService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails"/>
</bean>

<bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore"/>

<bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"/>
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true"/>
    <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="120"/>
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails"/>
</bean>
<bean id="userApprovalHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"/>
    <property name="requestFactory" ref="requestFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="requestFactory" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory">
    <constructor-arg name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails"/>
</bean>
<oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices" user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
    <oauth:authorization-code/>
    <oauth:implicit/>
    <oauth:refresh-token/>
    <oauth:client-credentials/>
    <oauth:password/>
</oauth:authorization-server>
<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" resource-id="test" token-services-ref="tokenServices"/>
<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">

    <oauth:client client-id="restapp1" authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,client_credentials" authorities="ROLE_APP" scope="read,write,trust" secret="secret"/>
    <oauth:client client-id="restapp2" authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit" secret="secret" authorities="ROLE_APP"/>
</oauth:client-details-service>
<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">

    <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler"/>
</sec:global-method-security>
<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler"/>
<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler"/>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
<!--<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"-->
<!--xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"-->
<!--xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"-->
<!--xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"-->
<!--xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">-->
<context:component-scan
        base-package="com.suraj.ecommerce.controller"/><!-- DispatcherServlet will search the controller class-->
<context:annotation-config/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/assets"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/><!--for using the map-->

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ecommerce"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>

</bean>

<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <property name="port" value="587" />
    <property name="username" value="abc@gmail.com " />
    <property name="password" value="abc" />

    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="mail" class="com.suraj.ecommerce.others.Mail"/>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.suraj.ecommerce.entity"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!--<bean id="signupService" class="com.suraj.ecommerce.service.SignUpService"/>-->

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="productDAOImpl" class="com.suraj.ecommerce.daoimpl.ProductDAOImpl"/>
<bean id="productService" class="com.suraj.ecommerce.service.ProductService"/>
<bean id="signupService" class="com.suraj.ecommerce.service.SignUpService"/>
<bean id="signupDAOImpl" class="com.suraj.ecommerce.daoimpl.SignUpDAOImpl"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Client secret that you are passing, *secret* is for client id *restapp1*

I guess you should pass *restapp* as the secret

Comment: restapp as a secret?

Comment: Using restapp also didn't help me. So, I edited it to secret and still not working.